# Mockery how to assert class instance

Tags: php, symfony, testing, mockery

Is there a way with mockery to assert that a mocked object should return a certain class instance ? how should a moked object achieve that ?

let's say i am using a mocked entity manager + repository ,which returns a mocked MyClass object.

i am unit testing a worker class which should return a MyClass instance (obviously not a mocked Myclass), using the repository.

the problem is that when i inject the mocked entity manager + repository, inside the worker it is working with a MockedMyClass instance , and when the repository "gets stuff from db", it returns the MockedMyclass object, simply because the mocked repository returns a mocked object.

how should i create a test like this ?
For reference, here is how i created the mocked objects

```
protected function getMockEM($empty = self::REPO_NOT_EMPTY)
{
    $emMock = M::mock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager', array(
            'persist' => null,
            'remove' => null,
            'flush' => null,
            'getRepository' => $this->getMockRepository($empty)
    ));
    return $emMock;
}

public function getMockMyClass()
{
    $pnMock = M::mock('MyNamespace\MyClass', array(
            'getUser'               =>  $this->getMockUser(),
            'getSchedule'           =>  $this->getMockSchedule($this->getDefaultStartingScheduleTime()),
            'getStartingTime'       =>  $this->getDefaultStartingScheduleTime(),
            'getNotificationTime'   =>  $this->getDefaultStartingScheduleTime()->modify("- ".$this->getDefaultNotificationTime()." minutes")
    ));

    return $pnMock;
}

public function getMockRepository($empty = self::REPO_NOT_EMPTY)
{
    if ($empty) {
        $repoMock = M::mock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', array(
            'findOneBy' => null
        ));
    } else {
        $repoMock = M::mock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', array(
            'findOneBy' => $this->getMockMyClass()
        ));
    }


    return $repoMock;
}
```

....

```
$this->assertSame('MyClass',get_class($worker->doMethodThatShouldReturnaMyClassInstance()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MockedMyClass extends MyClass you can check that the returned object is an instance of MyClass using `assertInstanceOf`.

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $worker->doMethodThatShouldReturnaMyClassInstance());
```

Comment: That's fantastic , i didn't know that. do you happen to have more resources on mockery except the default guide ? i find quite a lack of informations online

Comment: Yeah, it extends the original class so that it will continue to work in the same places, e.g. in [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). I don't know of any good resources other than the [main documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) unfortunately.